# Array method error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

So, I am trying to remove some elements from an array. I have 2 filters which I need to call. One is for filtering data with a search box and the other depending on a condition. But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

This is the component:

```
const PassengerCardBasedOnRoute = ({
  searchParam,
  passengerCardId,
  isAddToMyPassengersSuccess,
  unassignedDropOffPassengers,
}) => {

  // This is the filter that work based on a search parameter
  const filteredData = filterByParam =>
    filterByParam.filter(obj =>
      Object.keys(obj).some(key =>
        String(obj[key])
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()),
      ),
    );

  // Here is where I need to remove from the array the condition met
  const filterByPassengerCardId = passengersData => {
    remove(passengersData, info => {
      return info.id === passengerCardId;
    });
  };

  const componentToRenderBasedOnParams = info => (
    <View key={info.id}>
      {isAddToMyPassengersSuccess && info.id === passengerCardId && (
        <PassengersAdded name={info.name} id={info.id} />
      )}
      <PassengersInfo
        id={info.id}
        name={info.name}
        searchParam={searchParam}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const showFeedbackIfNoLength = data => {
    if (!passengerCardId && size(filteredData(data))) {
      filteredData(data).map(info => componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info));
    } else if (passengerCardId) {

      // HERE IS WHERE THE APP THROWS THE ERROR
      filteredData(filterByPassengerCardId(data)).map(info =>
        componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info),
      );

    } else {
      return <EmptyState>No records found</EmptyState>;
    }

    return data;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <OptionsModal>{<AllPassengersOptionsModal />}</OptionsModal>
      <View>
        {!navigationStore.index && unassignedDropOffPassengers
          ? showFeedbackIfNoLength(unassignedDropOffPassengers)
          : null}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**

And here comes the error:

```
  const filteredData = filterByParam =>
    // Here comes the error
    filterByParam.filter(obj =>
      Object.keys(obj).some(key =>
        String(obj[key])
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()),
      ),
    );
```

When this condition is met:

```
      // HERE IS WHERE THE APP THROWS THE ERROR
      filteredData(filterByPassengerCardId(data)).map(info =>
        componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info),
      );
```

When this other condition is met, everything works properly:

```
   if (!passengerCardId && size(filteredData(data))) {
      filteredData(data).map(info => componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info));
    }
```

What am I missing to achieve what I need?

Comment: On the 3 lines snippet you provided you don't access `.filter` property, an exception cannot be from that line but from somewhere else.

Comment: Hi @zerkms I just updated my code. Sorry.

Comment: Then the error means `filterByParam` is undefined. Which is not surprising given `filterByPassengerCardId` returns nothing.

Comment: The first condition is met properly and works: `if (!passengerCardId && size(filteredData(data))) {
      filteredData(data).map(info => componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info));
    }`

Comment: I suggest you look again. You are passing the return value from `filterByPassengerCardId(data)` into `filteredData()` but `filterByPassengerCardId` has no `return` statement therefore, it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in the expression `filteredData(filterByPassengerCardId(data))`, `filteredData` is expecting an `Array`; however, `filterByPassengerCardId(data)` returns undefined.

Change `filterByPassengerCardId`'s return value to an `Array` and the error should no longer be thrown.

Edit: Saw your comment that you're using Lodash's [`remove` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#remove) which does, in fact, return an `Array`.

In that case just edit `filterByPassengerCardId` to return the result of calling `remove`:

```
const filterByPassengerCardId = passengersData => {
  return remove(passengersData, info => {
    return info.id === passengerCardId;
  });
};
```

Edit: Or better yet, for conciseness:

```
const filterByPassengerCardId = passengersData => (
  remove(passengersData, ({id}) => id === passengerCardId)
);
```

Comment: The function `filterByPassengerCardId` takes a parameter `passengersData`, which when it gets call is `unassignedDropOffPassengers` which is a proper array. I think the issue is when I call `remove` on `filterByPassengerCardId`. It is not returning an array.

Comment: It is throwing `undefined`.

Comment: @Reacting in the `filteredData(filterByPassengerCardId(data))` expression `filterByPassengerCardId` returns `undefined`, then `undefined` is passed to the `filteredData`

Comment: I'm not sure where `remove` is defined, but even if `remove` does return an array, `filterByPassengerCardId` does not return the result of calling `remove`. I.e. if `remove` does return an array: `const filterByPassengerCardId = passengersData => {
    return remove(passengersData, info => {
      return info.id === passengerCardId;
    });
  };`

Answer (score 1):

The problems could come from here:

```
  // Here is where I need to remove from the array the condition met
  const filterByPassengerCardId = passengersData => {
    remove(passengersData, info => {
      return info.id === passengerCardId;
    });
  };
```

Maybe it is not working in a way you are expecting, at least it is not returning anything (returns undefined). While you may expect an array return from this function.

Comment: `unassignedDropOffPassengers` exists. See my comments below the post. There is some more info. I just updated the post as well.

Comment: It could be that `filterByPassengerCardId` function is not working as expected.

Comment: Yep, The function filterByPassengerCardId takes a parameter passengersData, which when it gets call is unassignedDropOffPassengers which is a proper array. I think the issue is when I call remove on filterByPassengerCardId. It is not returning an array.

Comment: @Reacting yes, I think this is the case!

Comment: That is remove from lodash -> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#remove what could I be doing wrong?